# Searchkick How to run exact query matching (Case insensitive)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, filter, rspec, searchkick

I am implementing an elasticsearch search method using searchkick. My settings are as follows:

```
#elastic search settings:
  searchkick 

 def search_data
    attributes.merge(
      title: title,
      last_name: author(&:last_name),
      publisher_name: publisher(&:name),
    )
end
```

My search is as follows:

```
self.search(query, fields: [:title, {publisher_name: :exact}, {last_name: :exact}]).records
```

However, if I am running rspec tests over factories, I am getting results which tells me exact is not working. For example:

```
author1 = create(:author, first_name: "Kate", last_name: "White")       
publisher1 = create(:publisher, name: "HarperCollins")
book1 = create(:book, title: "The Secrets You Keep: A Novel", author_id: author1.id, publisher_id: publisher1.id)

publisher3 = create(:publisher, name: "Pamela Dorman Books;")
author3 = create(:author, first_name: "Shari", last_name: "Lapena")  
book3 = create(:book, title: "Couple Next Door", author_id: author3.id, publisher_id: publisher3.id)


author4 = create(:author, first_name: "Lauren", last_name: "Graham")       
publisher4 = create(:publisher, name: "Ballantine Books")
book4 = create(:book, title: "Someday, Secrets Someday, Maybe", author_id: author4.id, publisher_id: publisher4.id)


author5 = create(:author, first_name: "Fictious", last_name: "Secrets")       
publisher5 = create(:publisher, name: "Ballantine Books")
book5 = create(:book, title: "Fictious Book 1", author_id: author5.id, publisher_id: publisher5.id)

author9 = create(:author, first_name: "Lauren", last_name: "xyz")       
publisher9 = create(:publisher, name: "Secrets halo")
book9 = create(:book, title: "Cool Book", author_id: author9.id, publisher_id: publisher9.id)
```

**Rspec query:**

```
expect(Book.search_instead_with_elastic_search('Secrets')).to match_array([book1, book4, book5, book9])
```

passes.

But if I have specified for exact, why is `"Secrets halo"` being considered? `book9` should not be included in my results.

Comment: For exact mapping you need to use the `term` or `terms` query. Not sure how you can do it if you are using `searchkick`

Comment: Is `search_instead_with_elastic_search` a method you defined yourself. Please add it to your question.